# Trying to make a div move when a function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making a `<div>` that I want to move from off the left side of the screen, to then take over the screen 100%.  I am having an issue though with getting it to slide over.  Here is my code so far [JSFiddle Sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/xBd8R/)

```
function show(){

var website = document.getElementById('website');
website.style.left = '0%;'

} /*  I know I don't have much, I did..  I just got it all wrong. */
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="show()" style="color:#999;">Superman - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a>
<div id="website">

<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman" width="100%">

</div>
```

CSS

```
#website{
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background:#666;
    width:100%;
    left:100%;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually want a sliding animation? I see no indication of how you want to do that, jQuery? native? CSS?

Comment: I want a sliding effect, but I was just settling for this for the moment.  If anyone knows how, that'd be great.  And I do have jQuery.  I just am new to javascript.

Comment: If you're building this in JSFiddle you need to make sure you export the `show` function. JSFiddle likes to wrap stuff. Add `window.show = show;` at the bottom of your script to export it. Current you will get the error: `Uncaught Referencerror: show is not defined.` Also, if you have jQuery and you intend to use it, you should.

Comment: I'm making it locally, and just putting it on JSFiddle to show my code.  The code I have is just doing, well, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see the error. You're gonna hate yourself for this one :D

```
website.style.left = '0%;'
                     // ^-- :D
```

Change to:

```
website.style.left = '0%';
```

Comment: Oh, my, God.  You are amazing my friend.  And I absolutely do, haha....   You deserve a cookie.